# Implementing Repository Pattern with Generated Code

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2015

Is there a way to implement the repository pattern in Asp.NET MVC  while also generating the controllers and views from a model?

One of the great features of Asp.NET MVC is that it will generate a lot of code for you based on your model. Unfortunately, it seems you need a model **AND** a DBContext class to do so. I have my MVC project referencing a repository, and both references the same models. Is there a way to generate the code using the model only?

Comment: I am not aware of such a thing but if someone knows, that would be a great feature actually. Only thing i can suggest is  might have to scaffold then Inject your dependencies (interface's) using a IOC Container and replace DbContext with that interface.

Comment: @HastaPasta I think you are right. Sometimes you just want to confirm what you think you already know!